Existence of a real function radial with specific properties
It is possible to think of the existence of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ radial of class $C^2_0$ that satisfies:
$\bullet$ $f = 1$ on $B_{R/2}(x_0)$ and $0 \leq f \leq 1$ on $\mathbb{R}^N \setminus B_{R/2}(X_0)$;
$\bullet$ $\mbox{supp}(f) \subset B_R(x_0)$;
$\bullet$ $|\nabla f| \leq 2/R$,
where $R > 0$, $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $B_{R}(x_0), B_{R/2}(x_0)$ are open balls?
Observation. I thought of something like a mollifier or a cut-off function, but I'm not convinced.
